# Issue with JPA not loading lazy fetched collection

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jpa, websphere

I'm having a problem with JPA refusing to fetch a collection that is set to fetch lazy.  Here are how the entities are defined:

Report Entity

```
//bi-directional many-to-one association to Host
@OneToMany(mappedBy="report", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Host> hosts;
```

Host Entity

```
//bi-directional many-to-one association to Report
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="INCIDENT_ID")
private Report report;
```

For some reason I can't get the hosts set to load into memory and hosts is always null.  I found the following on a stackoverflow post, but it doesn't work either:

```
public void loadHosts(Report report)
{
    PersistenceUtil unitUtil = getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil();
    System.out.println("isLoaded(report, \"hosts\"): " + unitUtil.isLoaded(report, "hosts"));
    initializeCollection(report.getHosts());
    System.out.println("isLoaded(report, \"hosts\"): " + unitUtil.isLoaded(report, "hosts"));
}

private void initializeCollection(Collection<?> collection) 
{
    if(collection == null) 
    {
        return;
    }
    collection.iterator().hasNext();
}
```

Output from the above:

```
SystemOut     O isLoaded(report, "hosts"): false
SystemOut     O isLoaded(report, "hosts"): false
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to call the getHosts between the session.get(object) and the tx.commit. Or you can also decide to use fetch=FetchType.EAGER (though thats propably not a good idea)

Comment: In this case I am reading an existing report from the database.  The report and related hosts were written to the database using these entities.  I've tried calling report.getHosts() and am doing that in the above code in the line: initializeCollection(report.getHosts());

Comment: Im sorry, I missed that line.

Comment: Would a fetchtype.eager still help?

Comment: It does work as eager, but there are several pages or datatables where I don't need to have the host data accessible.  Just trying to make efficient usage of memory by not loading what isn't needed.